# Getting MIB compile error: Sequence and Row should have related names

Tags: snmp, mib

On an MIB I have written I am getting the error

```
  Warning 10 : Sequence "XxxSequence" and Row "xxxEntry" should have related names
```

*smilint* is not giving any errors and *net-snmp* does not seem to care either.

Does anyone have a hint on what this error means, or how to correct it?

Comment: Open a standard RFC MIB document and see how it defines tables (naming conventions), and soon you will see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I was have trouble here is that it seems you have to have the SEQUENCE entry after the OBJECT-TYPE entry.

xxxEntry OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX  XxxEntry
        ...

XxxEntry ::= SEQUENCE {
         ...
  }

If you don't have them in the order then *smilint* will give you a *Only differ by case* warning.

*smilint* does not seem to care about the *related names* warning.